# Installing webpack ^4.42.1 gives me deprecated warnings

Tags: npm, webpack

I get the following two warnings on a `npm install`:

`npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated`

`npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated`

Not sure if we should just ignore this warning or fix it? If so, how.

Answer (score 0):

We don’t include these packages directly, they probably dependencies of some packages we use. Will check if I can figure out which packages are using them and if there is an update for them.

You can ignore them for now.

Comment: Who is "we"? Is this quoted text from somewhere?

Comment: Not sure if it meant to be an answer.